# JsonParseException while generating java wrapper object with web3j

Tags: solidity, web3j, android, java

so a few weeks ago I created a java wrapper object with web3j for a smart contract and was able to work with it with no problems. following exactly what I did a few weeks ago I keep getting a JsonParseException now without changing anything. The command I am using: 
`web3j solidity generate --javaTypes greeter_sol_Greeter.abi greeter_sol_Greeter.bin -o src/main/java -p com.example.ethgreeter`

and the error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: greeter_sol_Greeter.bin; line: 1, column: 32]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:503)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1689)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1426)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:876)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2740)
        at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.loadContractDefinition(SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.java:93)
        at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.generate(SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.java:116)
        at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.main(SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.java:87)
        at org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.run(SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.java:48)
        at org.web3j.console.Runner.main(Runner.java:38)
```

Does anyone have any clue why this could have started happening out of the blue? I am using web3j version 3.4.0, it is the same version I used a couple of weeks ago and it seems to be the latest version still. Here is a link for [web3j documentation](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: It was really a simple solution I feel a little embarrassed but just in case anyone runs into the same issue: when doing the command switch the abi and bin files so its like this: `web3j solidity generate --javaTypes <file name>.bin <file name>.abi -o src/main/java -p com.example.ethgreeter`